# Pylance does not recognize attribute from scipy

Tags: python, importerror, scipy.stats

I am trying to use the `scipy.stats.qmc` module, but I can't import it without an error message.
Has anyone an idea how to fix this problem?

I tried:

```
from scipy.stats import qmc
```

and

```
from scipy.stats.qmc import Sobol, QMCEngine
```

Every time I get shown the error:

> "Import "scipy.stats.qmc" could not be resolved"

or

> "Module "scipy.stats" has no attribute "qmc"".

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of SciPy you have.

```py
import scipy
scipy.__version__
```

[`scipy.stats.qmc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.qmc.html#module-scipy.stats.qmc) was [added in SciPy 1.7.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release/1.7.0-notes.html). If you have an earlier version, you can fix the problem by updating SciPy.

Comment: Hey, I use SciPy 1.11.4, so it seems like thats not the problem here. But thank you nontheless for your help!

Comment: Then if re-installing doesn't work, I'd suggest filling out a bug report: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/new?assignees=&labels=defect&projects=&template=Bug_report.yml&title=BUG%3A+%3CPlease+write+a+comprehensive+title+after+the+%27BUG%3A+%27+prefix%3E. Please be sure to include the "SciPy/NumPy/Python version and system information".